# Post Java-14 getter/setter naming convention

Tags: java, naming-conventions, getter, java-14, java-record

Java 14 introduced [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) feature. Record creates getter with the same name as field, so one would write `print(person.name())` for example. But old Java bean convention dictates that one should name this method as `getName()`.

Using both styles in the same code base does not look very nice. Migrating everything to records is not possible, as they are too limited to replace all use-cases.

Is there any official or semi-official guidelines how to name getters and setters after Java 14 in new code?

Comment: I suspect records are meant to be a different kind of component from standard javabeans, and perhaps it's right for them to follow a different line of conventions. They have different constraints, so they naturally won't fit in many places we find javabeans anyway.

Comment: I think the answer is no.  Not yet.  Style guides / conventions tend to *trail* the addition of new language features because it takes time for a consensus to emerge.

Comment: @user7294900 from the link in my question: "a record acquires many standard members automatically: ... A public read accessor method for each component of the state description, with the same name and type as the component".

Comment: Besides ... records will only be a "preview" feature in Java 14.   They won't necessarily make it to the stage of being a permanent language feature.

Comment: Just as a data point: Google's Java uses [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) widely at present, which is sort-of records-within-the-constraints-of-the-current-language. It is a reasonably common convention to omit "get" from getters; but some ardently push back (actually, [there's a specific point in the FAQ](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/howto.md#beans), saying "do either, just be consistent"). YMMV; Google style is but one of many choices.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am _so excited_ for Groovy/Kotlin/EL code where I need to write `obj.foo().bar.baz().quux`!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quote from [JEP 359](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359):

> It is not a goal to declare "war on boilerplate"; in particular, it is not a goal to address the problems of mutable classes using the JavaBean naming conventions.

My understanding, based on the same document is that *records* are `transparent holders for shallowly immutable data`.

That being said:

1. Records are not the place to look for getters/setters syntactical sugar, as they are not meant to replace JavaBeans.
2. I strongly agree with you that JavaBeans are too verbose. **Maybe** an additional feature (called *beans* instead of *records*) could be implemented - very similar behavior with the *records* feature but that would permit mutability. In that case, *records* and *beans* would not be mutually exclusive.
3. As it has been mentioned, records are in *preview* mode. Let's see what the feedback from community would be.

All in all, IMHO they are a step forward... I wrote [this example](https://github.com/knowledge-base-and-tutorials/java14-features/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/kbnt/java14/records/Records.java) set where you can see a code reduction to ~15% LOC from standard JavaBeans.

Also, note that `records behave like normal classes: they can be declared top level or nested, they can be generic, they can implement interfaces` (from the same document). You can actually partly simulate JavaBeans (only getters would make sense, though) by extracting an interface containing the getters - however that would be a lot of work and not a really clean solution...

So, based on the logic above, to address your question, **no** - I didn't see any (semi)official guideline for getters and setters and I don't think that there is a motivation for it right now because, again, records are not a replacement for JavaBeans...

Comment: Naming conventions are quite difficult to follow sometimes for synthetic code. For example, for te attribute `uuid` the getter could be `getUUID` and not `getUuid`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks. How does  having a get prefix to getters in records make it sound like it is a replacement for beans? It would just make it more consistent with existing conventions that this method is a getter.

Answer (score 7):

The `record` spec is now ["final" as of Java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/records.html) and this naming convention discrepancy has unfortunately not been addressed.  I stumbled upon it when attempting to leverage Records as shallow holder classes to implement interfaces part of an existing domain model.

Whilst this isn't as neat a solution as I'd like, Records can have methods, so you could add "legacy" getters to your `record`, as in the following (contrived but simple) example.

```java
public interface Nameable {
   public String getName();
}

public record Person(String name) implements Nameable {
   public String getName() {
      return name;   // or return name();
   }
}
```

At least this allows client code to continue to use that tried and tested (over 20 years old) convention, which - let's face it - is used far more than in pure JavaBeans context.

> You could say that the language designers have lived up to their remit of "not declaring war on boilerplate"

Comment: Did you consider naming your component `getName` if you really need the accessor name to be `getName`?

Comment: IMHO `public record Person(String getName)` impairs the code's readability; even more so if the field is being referenced the record's method(s).  Also, do consider that in the above scenario, we're not discussing mere preference, but the need to retrofit an existing API (`Nameable`), which one may or may not have the ability to alter...

Comment: I am currently also considering naming the field like the getter but I agree there should be a way to change the name of the getter method. On the other side would this make working with foreign records more confusing, since you can't differentiate between getters amd other methods.

Comment: Naming the field like the getter is a terrible idea, especially if you want to serialize the record. Then you will have a "getName": "Brad Idea" in your JSON ;)

Answer (score 4):

I figured I'd address one tacit assumption: that the style guides we have now actually recommend Bean style getters and setters.

None of the style guides I found actually recommend it. One of them remarks that people are divided on the issue. Thus, if you use the convention `foo()` and `foo(newValue)`, you would be consistent with readily available style guides.

#### Guides

[Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) does show some `getField` methods, but the actual guidance doesn't mention them.

[Brown](https://brown-cs18-master.github.io/content/resources/java-style.pdf) borrows from Google, same.

[Cornell](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/JavaAndDS/JavaStyle.html#NameMethod) says:

> However, a convention in Java is that a function that yields the value of a field (say title) is the name of the field preceded by "get". People are of two minds on this; not everyone thinks it's a good idea. The name "title" could also be used.

[Java Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html) same as Google.

[Eydean](https://eydean.github.io/styleguide/javaguide) borrows heavily from Google and Sun, same as Google.

[Twitter](https://github.com/twitter-archive/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md) borrows from Google, same as Google.

And lastly, the [Java Beans Spec](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javabeans-spec.html) lays out exactly how you name getters and setters to be compatible with Beans in §8.3.1:

> **Simple properties**
> By default, we use design patterns to locate properties by looking for methods of the form:
>
> ```
> public <PropertyType> get<PropertyName>();
> public void set<PropertyName>(<PropertyType> a);
> ```
>
> If we discover a matching pair of “get<*PropertyName*>” and “set<*PropertyName*>” methods
> that take and return the same type, then we regard these methods as defining a read-write property whose name will be “<*propertyName*>”. We will use the “get<*PropertyName*>” method
> to get the property value and the “set<*PropertyName*>” method to set the property value. The
> pair of methods may be located either in the same class or one may be in a base class and the
> other may be in a derived class.

And even if you completely disregard this:

> § 8.6 A Java Bean can also explicitly specify which properties, events, and methods it supports by providing a class that implements the BeanInfo interface.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled up this when researching naming conventions for my project. Looking at the "recent" additions to the std lib (e.g. Path, FileSystem, HttpRequest, ...) the only more-or-less "pattern" I could detect was that `.prop()` implies direct, unmodified access to the field value, and thus existance of the field with that very type.

Whereas "getXXX" conveys that you cannot/should not assume the existence of a field. This property might be calculated, direct field access or read-only wrapped (e.g. `List.copyOf`) or converted.

So my conclusion is: if you want to communicate "structure" or enforce the precence of fields use `.prop()`. In all other cases stick to `getXXX` as it is more flexible (implementers can be entity classes, records or service classes.

Btw: I am aware that there are big offenders to this logic even in the jdk. e.g. `BigDecimal` that's why I focused on more recent additions.

Answer (score -3):

In Java records, object fields *must be private and final*.
So there is just one kind of getter and one kind of setter possible.

In Java classes, object fields may be private or public.
In the latter type of field, one can get or set them simply by adding a period and the field name, e.g.

```
 Employee emp = new Employee(); // Nullary constructor
 emp.name = "John Schmidt";     // Setter
 . . . 
 . . . 
 if (emp.name != "Buddy")       // Getter
 {
    emp.bonus = 100.00;
 }
```

Non-private fields are used a lot in Android apps to save memory and time extracting data. But there's no reason not to use them in Java where it's safe to do so.

Now, if you change away from the usual way in Java classes to something like that used in record types, e.g.

```
String name = emp.name();  // New getter convention for private field
```

you have a serious risk of confusion by code readers who might misinterpret this as a non-private object field.

And if you change the record getter to what is used in Java objects, i.e.

```
obj.getField()
```

then there is a risk of confusion by coder reviewers and possibly a compiler may treat it as a Java object, depending on execution decision criteria.

In short, it's a different type of object to the normal Java class or enum. Its accessors indicate this new type unambiguously.
That's how I see it anyhow.
Maybe someone on the Java development committee may be able to enlighten us further.

Comment: You noticed that fields and methods are in different namespaces?

Comment: Even if you read code with a mouse hovering over the field of view (and I don't and doubt if you do either, buddy) this wouldn't *immediately* jump up at you. Eclipse just uses little colored squares and circles to signify namespaces. IntelliJ is even sparer by default. But I suppose you have configured it to show this essential info.