# No default constructor found with Java record and BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-14, java-record

I am playing with the new Java 14 and Spring Boot. I have used the new cool record instead of a regular Java class for data holders.

```
public record City(Long id, String name, Integer population) {}
```

Later in my service class, I use Spring `BeanPropertyRowMapper` to fetch data.

```
@Override
public City findById(Long id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id = ?";
    return jtm.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id},
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(City.class));
}
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zetcode.model.City]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.zetcode.model.City.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:145) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
```

How to add a default constructor for a record or is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: How about implementing `java.io.Serializable`? such as `public record City(Long id, String name, Integer population) implements java.io.Serializable {}`?

Comment: @Naman Still the same error. I have managed to run the example with a custom `RowMapper`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [DataClassRowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/DataClassRowMapper.html). It works fine with records.

```
@Override
public City findById(Long id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id = ?";
    return jtm.queryForObject(sql, new DataClassRowMapper<>(City.class), id);
}
```

Comment: Great, it works. I have modified the snippet so that it does not use the deprecated method.

Comment: thanks! this should be changed to the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

Just declare it explicitly by providing default for fields:

```
public record City(Long id, String name, Integer population) {
    public City() {
        this(0L, "", 0)
    }
}
```

An important note. **BeanPropertyRowMapper** scans setters/getters to inflate your record instance, as **record** is immutable, there is not setter and it's not compatible with java beans specification, you'll get and empty record. Please, read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981081/post-java-14-getter-setter-naming-convention). The only way to create a record is by using a constructor. So, you have two options: either use plain java bean or implement your custom row mapper.

The esiest way how it may look like is this:

```
@Override
public City findById(final Long id) {
    final var sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id = ?";
    return jtm.queryForObject(
            sql,
            new Object[]{ id },
            (rs, rowNum) -> new City(
                    rs.getLong("id"),
                    rs.getString("name"),
                    rs.getInt("population")));
}
```

or you may use [reflection](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359):

> Reflection API
>
> The following public methods will be added to java.lang.Class:
>
> ```
> RecordComponent[] getRecordComponents()
> boolean isRecord()
> ```
>
> The method getRecordComponents() returns an array of
>   java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent objects, where
>   java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent is a new class. The elements of this
>   array correspond to the record’s components, in the same order as they
>   appear in the record declaration. Additional information can be
>   extracted from each RecordComponent in the array, including its name,
>   type, generic type, annotations, and its accessor method.
>
> The method isRecord() returns true if the given class was declared as
>   a record. (Compare with isEnum().)

Using those methods and [Class#getConstructor(Class... parameterTypes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) and [Constructor#newInstance(Object... initargs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) you can dynamically create record. But keep it in mind that reflection may bring some overhead and affect you performace.

I've added an example of [RecordRowMapper](https://github.com/sleshJdev/incubator/blob/master/spring-jdbc-record-row-mapper/src/main/java/by/slesh/spring/jdbc/core/RecordRowMapper.java) using reflection and a couple of [tests](https://github.com/sleshJdev/incubator/blob/master/spring-jdbc-record-row-mapper/src/test/java/by/slesh/spring/jdbc/core/AppTest.java):

```
package by.slesh.spring.jdbc.core;

import org.springframework.jdbc.IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

public class RecordRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<T> {
    private final Constructor<T> ctor;
    private final List<Arg> args;

    public RecordRowMapper(final Class<T> model) {
        if (!model.isRecord()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    model + " should be a record class");
        }
        final RecordComponent[] components = model.getRecordComponents();
        this.args = new ArrayList<>(components.length);
        final Class<?>[] argTypes = new Class[components.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < components.length; ++i) {
            final RecordComponent c = components[i];
            this.args.add(new Arg(i, c.getName(), c.getType()));
            argTypes[i] = c.getType();
        }
        try {
            this.ctor = model.getConstructor(argTypes);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Couldn resolve constructor for types " + Arrays.toString(argTypes));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T mapRow(final ResultSet resultSet, final int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
        final var metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        final int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        if (columnCount < args.size()) {
            throw new IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException(
                    args.size(), columnCount);
        }
        try {
            return ctor.newInstance(extractCtorParams(
                    resultSet, createPropertyToColumnIndexMap(
                            metaData, columnCount)));
        } catch (InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private Object[] extractCtorParams(
            final ResultSet resultSet,
            final Map<String, Integer> propertyToColumnIndexMap)
            throws SQLException {
        final var params = new Object[args.size()];
        for (final var arg : args) {
            final int columnIndex = propertyToColumnIndexMap.get(arg.name);
            params[arg.order] = JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(
                    resultSet, columnIndex, arg.type);
        }
        return params;
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> createPropertyToColumnIndexMap(
            final ResultSetMetaData metaData,
            final int columnCount)
            throws SQLException {
        final Map<String, Integer> columnPropertyToIndexMap = new HashMap<>(columnCount);
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; ++columnIndex) {
            final String propertyName = JdbcUtils.convertUnderscoreNameToPropertyName(
                    JdbcUtils.lookupColumnName(metaData, columnIndex));
            columnPropertyToIndexMap.put(propertyName, columnIndex);
        }
        return columnPropertyToIndexMap;
    }

    private static record Arg(int order, String name, Class<?>type) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is gone but the data is not fetched; `findById` returns the empty record. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: It's because records are not compatible with java beans specification. Not sure if you can use records in your case. Please, read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981081/post-java-14-getter-setter-naming-convention)

Comment: BeanPropertyRowMapper scans setters/getters to inflate your model. Records are immutable. Only way to create record is using constructor. So, you have two options: either use plain java bean or implement your custom row mapper.

Comment: An [explanation](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-dev/2020-May/006009.html) from Java Architect why they didn't follow JavaBeans convention.