# Java getter/setter naming convention when also using records

Tags: java, record, getter-setter

Is there any change to the Java getter/setter conventions (`getValue()` and `setValue()`) with the recent introduction of records? I'm asking because it seems odd to use the `get`/`set` prefixes in conjunction with the `value()` variant generated from records across a codebase.

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post Java-14 getter/setter naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981081/post-java-14-getter-setter-naming-convention)